# UNITY3d The Camera Follow and Background move are not smooth

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I just learn Unity3d for a while, then I have a question about The Camera Follow and Background move are not smooth. I create a cube with ragidbody2d , then i use two dufferent ways to make camera follow :
a. I make the camera in the cube
b. I use Script to control the camera (lateupdate use)

And I add some pictures which are converted into sprite （the size is 1024*512）. I make them to backgound.

when play it , both methods have the same problem, the background move is not smooth, but not completely smooth at all，it will appear from time to time.

I tried the official 2d example found in fast-moving role the backgound is not smooth too. But there are some game made by Unity like badland, when I play it ,there is no this problem.I dont know how to solve this problem, Is the camera configured ? Scirpt? The Type of texture? compressed way? or Need to use some plug-ins?
please help me .thank you .

Answer (score 2):

use  "LateUpdate"
LateUpdate is called after all Update functions have been called. This is useful to order script execution. For example a follow camera should always be implemented in LateUpdate because it tracks objects that might have moved inside Update.

Answer (score 1):

It probably because the updates you're using are not synced.

There's the main update (triggered each frame, time between those are different (Time.deltaTime)), FixedUpdate (triggered every physics update, which is a fixed time (Time.fixedTime)) and LateUpdate (every frame, but at the very last).

If you're trying to follow a rigidbody affected by physics, it's recommended to set the camera update function to Late- or FixedUpdate.

You can use it in the Update function if you set the interpolation of the rigidbody in it's inspector:

A rigidody gets an update for it's position every x fixed time, the Update function can be triggered 5 times when FixedUpdate has only been called once, or vice versa. This will give strange results, so setting the rigidbodies interpolation will smooth things out between those unsynced updates.

Also, you can move the camera smoothly by using Lerp methods. an example:

```
void Update() {
    Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * 5);
}
```

more about lerping [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I found another problem that I don't move camera at all, just move a GameObject which has some pictures as backgound. The Script of Moving GameObject is

Update()

```
this.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 40.0f, Space.World);
```

or

```
Vector3 pos = this.transform.position;
pos.x += (100.0f * Time.deltaTime);
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * 50);
```

the reuslt is the background move is not smooth with a visual lag, but not completely smooth at all，it will appear from time to time.

Is there some configures wrong? Graphics Emulation？ or something else ?